# Jquery File Upload invoking upload handler on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using jQuery File Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). I am using Terascript for my server side upload handler and it seems to work fine.

But unfortunately jQuery File Upload seems to want to invoke the upload handler on load, before you have told it what files you want to upload and manually triggered the upload. The upload handler creates an random name but of course there is no actual file associated with it.

http://dev.over60travel.com/sandbox/jquery-file-uploads/index.html

Afterwards it all seems to work fine. But why does it trigger an upload on load?

Comment: Did you copy the whole demo website? Just use the javascript function that you need and update your question accordingly. There are thousands of lines of code in the demo page but you only need a few ones. Better read the documentation of how to use the jquery plugin.

Comment: This would be a better starting point imho: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin
You need the <input> and the corresponding javascript snippet for a simple setup.

Comment: I copied the entire archive to my server but only modified the one version (Basic Plus UI) as per the instructions in the documentation. I changed a line in main.js from 'server/php/' to '/utils/image_upload.taf'. I also changed the name of the input field from 'files[]' to 'files' as my upload handler doesn't like the [].

Comment: I modified all other versions so they are all functional now. Basic and Basic Plus work fine. Basic Plus UI, AngularJS and JQuery UI all exhibit the issue.

Comment: I have removed all the unnecessary menus and blockquotes so it is more barebones.

Comment: I have found an ugly workaround.

My upload handler tests whether there is a file included in the postargs and if not, exits. No JSON reponse resutls in no response on screen.

Not the ideal workaround, and I'd still like to know if calling the upload handler on load is correct behaviour but it's a result.

Comment: I've put the upload handler back to how it was initially incase anyone wants to look into the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Sebastian Tschan, the author of jQuery-File-Upload, for the answer to this question.

On load the app does indeed call the upload module. I'm still not entirely sure why but the way to stop it is to comment out the follwoing lines from 'main.js'.

```
        // Load existing files:
//    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
//    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
//        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
//        dataType: 'json',
//        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
//    }).always(function () {
//        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
//    }).done(function (result) {
//        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
//            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
//    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It dawned on me on Friday evening that this is actually a file management (rather than upload) interface. On load you are requesting a list of existing files and that is the process that was causing my issue. Sorry for being a bit slow. ;)

I had changed my upload handler so that if it is called without a file argument it returned nothing. That was my original cure. Then Sebastian suggested removal of the code that requests it onload and that was a better solution. Now that I understand why it is called onload I thought I would have a try at getting it working as initially intended.

I have uncommented the code and changed my upload handler so that if no file argument is sent, it returns JSON in the format specified in the documentation. Awesome!